# Objects made up of electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

Say you have a neutral rod, and you bring a positively charged rod beside it (call the side the charged rod is brought near side A and the other side side B). The electrons from the side B will start moving towards side A and the positively charged nuclei in side A will start moving to side B.

After a large part of side A consists of only of electrons, the electrons would start repelling each other and the movement of charges will stop. But at this point a very large portion of side A consists of electrons and a large part of side B consists only of positively charged nuclei. The system is at equilibrium.

But the rod has now been mostly split into a electron side and a positively charged nuclei side, however it doesn't look different at all? Why? Shouldn't a rod made of atoms look and be completely different than a rod that is mostly made up of electrons on one side and nuclei on the other?

I know that electrons are very small, and since side A mostly consists of electrons, shouldn't it be almost invisible?

Comment: You should calculate for what amount of charge how many electrons and what mass is shifted, you would be pleasantly surprised !

Comment: Another hint: if the rods should spark across, calculate the rough diameter of the resulting crater (in kilometers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solid material is not made of electrons separated from the nuclei. The nuclei and electrons live together in a structure that can be ordered (like crystals) or not (like glass). In all cases, the electron arrangement around the nuclei is very important as it allows for bonding between these atoms. In that process, some electrons are stuck close to the nuclei, they are called 'bound' electrons. Others are not totally stuck and can somewhat move from atom to atom, they are called 'free' electrons. But the atoms are always stuck in a given position. That's why the rod stays as a rod and does not evaporate as a gas.

Imagine that the fixed atoms form a given stable structure. The free electrons can move inside this structure. These are the ones that are attracted to one side or the other. The nuclei do not move. That's why the rod just looks the same all the time: only a tiny number of electrons actually travel along.

Comment: But free electrons exist because they nuclei has a weak "pull" on them. If you bring a rod that is *extremely* positively charged, couldn't you theoretically break all electrons from their nuclei?

Comment: And also, wouldn't most of the positively charged nuclei + non-free electrons move to side B so most of side A would be free electrons?

Comment: To separate the electrons apart from the nuclei, you would have to bring an electric field of very high intensity. That's not happening in your case. It's possible to make it happen, but the material becomes a plasma before you have time to separate electrons far from the ions and that generally explodes or at least becomes gaseous.

Comment: It can't be that high, since electrons are separated from nuclei all the time in chemical reactions. How come those atoms don't explode or turn into plasma? Am I missing something?

Comment: The electrons that you can exchange in chemical reactions are the same ones that become 'free' in a solid. They are 'easy' to separate from the nuclei. The other ones are much more strongly attached to the nuclei. If you apply enough voltage, you could separate even those, but you would do that only on just a few electrons, or you would require a lot of current in your electrical system. For example this works in gases where people create plasmas by putting high voltage, but not in solids. To keep the plasma stable for more than nanoseconds, you need a closed loop anyway.

Comment: Got it. So only the free electrons move. But in addition to the free electrons moving one way, do the charged nuclei + non-free electrons move the other way?

Comment: @dfg even the "free" electrons move very slowly in most solid materials. It is the separation of charges that moves. Visualize a line of atoms beginning at A, in a row A1,A2,A3...An , in a chain joined by  the spill over fields of the neutral atoms. (Look up Van der Waals forces).  A charged rod pulls out an outer electron from An. An now positive pulls out an electron from A(n-1) and so on. The real motions are small and there is a drift velocity that can be measured. In metals where electrons move in bands it is faster, but still it is by passing the buck that the charge moves.

Comment: 1) Why would the free electron always move towards the direction of the other atom? For example if I place the charged rod under it, why wouldn't it just leave the solid from the "top"?

Comment: 2)If side A is positively charged, what makes the positive charges stay together? Why would they remain in the shape of a rod instead of moving apart to the maximum possible distance?

Comment: to your 2), The separation of charges is causing an electric field too small compared to the one binding the atoms together.